# understrap child theme - scss changes are not appied/visible

Tags: sass, wordpress-theming

I am having problems with "creating" an Understrap Child theme.

I am using Visual Studio Code and I have a plug in Live Sass Compiler.

The problem I am facing is that when I change/create the variables in _theme.scss and save it, no changes are shown on the website.

My child theme structure:

```
-understrap-child
   *functions.php
   *index.php
   *style.css
   -sass
     -theme
        *_theme.scss
        *_theme_variables.scss
```

My understanding is that a scss file with an underline is a partial scss file, and as such is not a stand alone file. If I save a regular scss file, without an underline it creates a regular file.

So my questions comes down to, do I need another .scss / .css file where the values from _theme.scss would be applied?

If I can provide any additional information, please let me know.

Edit1:

I think the problem is that I am not importing the underscore/partial files to any other non-underscore files. Since underscore files are partials, I am quite sure they need to be imported into non-underscore / specific files?

VScode - Live Sass Compile console

```
--------------------
Watching...
--------------------
Change Detected...
_theme_variables.scss
--------------------
Compiling Sass/Scss Files: 
--------------------
Watching...
--------------------
Change Detected...
_theme.scss
--------------------
Compiling Sass/Scss Files:
```

---

Edit2:

I have downloaded an understrap-child theme from github, but the problem persists.

---

Edit3:

I have not resolved this problem. I am now using another theme without issue.

Comment: did you @import "_theme_variables" in _theme?

Comment: I didn't. Although my _theme_variable is empty at the moment. I only added `body{ background: red;}` to _theme to see if it works.

Comment: write var colors in _variable_theme.scss then import this file to _theme.scss ,
in the top of  <code> _theme.scss</code> write : <code>@import '_variable_theme.scss'</code>, try it.

Answer (score 0):

write variables colors in

> `_variable_theme.scss`

then import this file in :

> `_theme.scss` ==>
> `@import '_variable_theme.scss'`

for example:

```css
//_variables_theme.scss

   $primary-color: #302AE6;
    $secondary-color: #536390;
    $font-color: #424242;
    $bg-color: #fff;
    $heading-color: #292922;
```

```css
// _theme.scss

@import '_variable_theme.scss'

body{background:$primary-color}
```

, try it.

Comment: Tried it, but nothing changed.

Comment: did you click on "watch" bottom on vs code?

Comment: I did =) I sometimes forget but not this time. 
PS: edited the question

Comment: correction: `@import '_variable_theme.scss';` 
was missing the `;` .

Comment: @HosseinAzizdokht I'm not able to see result of editing `$primary` color in `_theme_variables.scss` , where am I going wrong ?
[Full question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72825027/understrap-child-theme-edit-not-visible-sass-color-variable-not-applied)

Answer (score 0):

I faced [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72825027/understrap-child-theme-edit-not-visible-sass-color-variable-not-applied). If you're using an `understrap-child` theme, the variable overrides can be made on `src/sass/theme/_child_theme_variables.scss`; I was able to successfully modify `$primary` value here.

The earlier mistake was expecting theme changes on modifying `src/sass/assets/understrap/theme/_theme_variables.scss` !!