# Understrap child-theme edit not visible, sass color variable not applied

Tags: css, sass, wordpress-theming, bootstrap-5

I'm looking to change the primary theme color applied by `$primary` in `_theme_variables.scss`; changed value from default `$purple` to `$orange` while `npm run watch-bs` (browser-sync). Still no change on home page:

[image: screenshot of theme dev UI]

My edits:

`_theme_variables.scss`

```
$purple: #5533ff; // Thats a sample how you could change a BootStrap variable.
$orange:  #fd7e14;
$primary: $orange;  // Once we've changed the value, we'll also make it the primary brand color.
```

`_theme.scss`:

```
// This is an empty scss file for your custom styles - Please add your super duper awesome mega design styles here
@import "theme_variables";
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Please read here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/

Comment: @HDP thanks for the documentation. However, that doesn't answer my query as to why the change of  `$primary` color value in the `_theme_variables.scss` doesn't reflect on the homepage ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I solved this particular issue.
I was able to successfully override `$primary` value by modifying `src/sass/theme/_child_theme_variables.scss`.

The earlier mistake was expecting theme changes on editing `src/sass/assets/understrap/theme/_theme_variables.scss` !!

If anyone can delineate the purpose of `_child_theme_variables.scss` vs `_theme_variables.scss` in this context, I'll accept their answer !